# Can we declare global variables in Big Query which could be used in different statements

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I want to create a set of global variables which I can use anywhere in my SQL statements.

DECLARE has to be included every time in the query, but, for example, I want to include some set of strings multiple times in the queries as part of REG_EXP or IN statement. How we can achieve that?

```sql
DECLARE start_date  DATE DEFAULT DATE ("2023-01-01"); 
DECLARE end_date    DATE DEFAULT DATE ("2023-12-23"); 
DECLARE title_keyword     STRING DEFAULT "abc|xyz";
```

Comment: BQ supports session variables: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/sessions-write-queries#session_variables

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean that you would want to have access to the same value in many different queries?
If so, you could create a UDF:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION mydataset.funfun(x STRING)
RETURNS DATE
AS (
  CASE x
    WHEN "start_date" THEN DATE "2023-01-01"
    WHEN "end_date" THEN DATE "2023-12-01"
    ELSE NULL
  END
);
```

which you can then use in any query other query

```sql
SELECT funfun("start_date");
```